# SDE for Brownian motion on a circle

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Brownian motion on a circle can be generated by $\left(\cos\left(B_t\right),\sin\left(B_t\right)\right)$ where $B$ is Brownian motion on the real line. My question is what SDE was solved to get this as the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$g(t,x)={{e}^{ix}}=(\cos x,\sin x)$$
$${{y}_{t}}=({{y}_{1}},{{y}_{2}})$$
$${{y}_{t}}={{e}^{i{{B}_{t}}}}$$
$$g(t,x)={{e}^{ix}}\xrightarrow{x={{B}_{t}}}{{e}^{i{{B}_{t}}}}=(\cos {{B}_{t}},\sin {{B}_{t}})$$
$$\xrightarrow{{{y}_{t}}=({{y}_{1}},{{y}_{2}})}{{y}_{1}}=\cos {{B}_{t}},\overset{{}}{\mathop{{}}}\,{{y}_{2}}=\sin {{B}_{t}}$$

$$d{{y}_{t}}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}{{|}_{(t,{{B}_{t}})}}dt+\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}{{|}_{(t,{{B}_{t}})}}d{{B}_{t}}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{{{\partial }^{2}}g}{\partial {{x}^{2}}}{{|}_{(t,{{B}_{t}})}}{{(d{{B}_{t}})}^{2}}$$
$$0dt+(-\sin {{B}_{t}},\cos {{B}_{t}})d{{B}_{t}}+\frac{1}{2}(-\cos {{B}_{t}},-sin{{B}_{t}}){{(d{{B}_{t}})}^{2}}$$
$$=0dt+(-\sin {{B}_{t}},\cos {{B}_{t}})d{{B}_{t}}+\frac{1}{2}(-\cos {{B}_{t}},-sin{{B}_{t}})dt$$
${{y}_{1}}=\cos {{B}_{t}},\overset{{}}{\mathop{{}}}\,{{y}_{2}}=\sin {{B}_{t}}$
$$d{{y}_{t}}=(-{{y}_{2}},{{y}_{1}})d{{B}_{t}}+\frac{1}{2}(-{{y}_{1}},-{{y}_{2}})dt\\ $$
or
$$\\\left\{ \begin{matrix}
   d{{y}_{1}}=-{{y}_{2}}d{{B}_{t}}-\frac{1}{2}{{y}_{1}}dt  \\
   d{{y}_{2}}=+{{y}_{1}}d{{B}_{t}}-\frac{1}{2}{{y}_{2}}dt  \\
\end{matrix} \right.\\$$
Matrix form
$$\\dY=\frac{-1}{2}Y.dt+K.Y.dB_t$$
K is
$$K=\left( \begin{matrix}
   0 & -1  \\
   1 & 0  \\
\end{matrix} \right)\\$$
.