# SDE for Brownian motion on $S^n$

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, random-walk, stochastic-differential-equations

How can we find the SDE of the standard Brownian motion on $S^1$ and $S^2$?
In the the following link
[Brownian motion on $S^1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1774997/sde-for-brownian-motion-on-a-circle)
, the answer to the question was started with the solution of the SDE, however

1) how one can formally(and informally) obtain the SDE of the two processes?

In the work

[The random motion on the sphere generated by the Laplace-Beltrami operator](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266046528_The_random_motion_on_the_sphere_generated_by_the_Laplace-Beltrami_operator)

the SDEs are given for $S^1$ and $S^2$, but there is no explanation for that.

2) Why do we have a drift term in the SDE on $S^2$ (I'm interested in the **standard** BM)

I would appreciate your answer.

Comment: You take a standard Brownian motion in the tangent plane and project it using the exponential map. The geodesic properties of that map lead to the involvement of the Dirac/Laplace operator if you express it directly in points of the manifold. // The drift term is a correction that pushes the tangential motion of the $dB$ terms back onto the manifold.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3726179/227280