# Infinitesimal generator of the Brownian motion on a circle

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations, stochastic-pde

As explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/694227/what-is-the-importance-of-the-infinitesimal-generator-of-brownian-motion), the infinitesimal generator of a Brownian motion is $\frac{1}{2}\Delta$.
Can someone please provide (for a non-stochastic-student) the proof of finding the infinitesimal generator on a circle (and if possible, also on a sphere) in the Cartesian coordinates? (or introducing a book or article)

Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "on a circle?"

Comment: I mean the stochastic process with the following SDE:
$$
\\\left\{ \begin{matrix}
   d{{y}_{1}}=-{{y}_{2}}d{{B}_{t}}-\frac{1}{2}{{y}_{1}}dt  \\
   d{{y}_{2}}=+{{y}_{1}}d{{B}_{t}}-\frac{1}{2}{{y}_{2}}dt  \\
\end{matrix} \right.\\

which was discussed here :

[link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1774997/sde-for-brownian-motion-on-a-circle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from
$$dY_1=-\frac12 Y_1 dt-Y_2 dB_t, \\
  dY_2=-\frac12 Y_2 dt+Y_1 dB_t, $$

and using the general formula for the generator of a diffusion process $dX_t=f(X_t)dt+g(X_t)dB_t$, which reads
$$\mathcal{A}=\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x)\partial_{x_i}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m g_{ij}(x)\partial_{x_i}\partial_{x_j},$$
we have with $n=2$ and $m=1$
$$\mathcal{A}=\frac12\left(-y_1\partial_{y_1}-y_2\partial_{y_2}+y_2^2\partial_{y_1}^2+y_1^2\partial_{y_2}^2\right)=\frac12\partial_{\theta}^ 2.$$
Which is one half times the Laplacian on $S_1$.

In fact, one of the definitions of Brownian motion on a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ is that its generator is $\frac12\Delta_g$, where $\Delta_g$ is the Laplacian of $g$. Thus in order to find the generator of Brownian motion on $S_2$ in Cartesian coordinates, take the Laplacian on $S_2$ and transform it to Cartesian coordinates (a slightly tedious calculation).

Comment: Thank you very much. Above, we applied the general formula of the generator to the SDE.  The general formula is clear, but what is the starting point on $S_2$?
On $S_1$ we started with $Y= (cos(B),sin(B))$ and then applied the Ito formula to obtain the SDE. Unlike the circle case where we had only $B$, In case of sphere, don't we have $B_1$ and $B_2$? I mean :
$Y=( cos(B_1)sin(B_2), sin(B_1)sin(B_2), cos(B_1))$ ?
If so, what is the ito formula(SDE) obtained from $Y$? Can we use the same general formula for generator you wrote above for this SDE?

Comment: A Brownian motion on the chart does not lead to a Brownian motion on the manifold in general. You may want to think how you want to define/construct the Brownian motion if starting from the Laplacian is not satisfactory. You may come up with a number of constructions but you have to decide whether your construction is Brownian motion. I would suggest to ask a new question.